# Git не игнорирует файл

Tags: git

Все пытаюсь разобраться с git и каждый раз с этой штукой проблемы.
Закоммитил случайно ненужную папку. Пытался исправить это следующим образом:

1. удалить папку, добавить её в .gitignore
2. очистить кеш `git rm -r --cached .`
3. добавить все обратно `git add .`
4. сделать коммит

По идее, ненужная папка должна быть проигнорирована, но как бы не так.
Как будто бы теперь git о ней не знает (`git status` ее не выводит), но когда она снова создается, он ее замечает. Точнее даже не ее, а файлы в ней: **index.pug** и **style.scss**

Пытался удалять эти файлы из кеша отдельно `git rm #src/pug/pages/index.pug` (аналогично для style.scss)
Но это вызывает ошибку о том, что я якобы неправильно использую команду:

```
usage: git rm [<options>] [--] <file>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -q, --quiet           do not list removed files
    --cached              only remove from the index
    -f, --force           override the up-to-date check
    -r                    allow recursive removal
    --ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched
```

Знаю, по-хорошему бы пройти какой нибудь курс по git, но сейчас я просто хочу сохранить текущую версию этого проекта без лишних файлов

Вот структура проекта:

```
├── #src
│   ├── scss
│   │   └── style.scss
│   └── pug
│       ├── pages
│       │   └── index.pug
│       └── blocks
├── #dist
├── node_modules
├── .gitignore
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
└── package-look.json
```

Папка, которую не получается удалить из git - `#src`

Comment: Ее имя с решетки начинается? Если да, то ее надо экранировать в .gitignore

Comment: как говорится, а ларчик просто открывался... теперь работает корректно, спасибо за помощь